# Google Vision Accent Character Set NodeJs

Tags: node.js, special-characters, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to use Google Vision service with NodeJs. However when I request a text detection of an image, it gives only English Alphabet characters (characters without accents) which is not enough for me. How can I get the UTF-32 characters?

For example: the real text "öğrenci" but the service returns "ogrenci"

Answer (score 1):

I have used a 'languageHints' to detect a Hebrew text.

Let's say your call is:

```
vision.detectText(file)
```

so you can add the 'languageHints' in a following way:

```
var options = {
  imageContext: {
    languageHints: ["he", "iw", "en"],
  }
};

vision.detectText(file, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ogrenci is not ideal in Turkish, is it? Have you tried supplying Turkish as a language hint when you make the call?

Check out the languageHints section of the API:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate